# How to use `index.js` in a Node.js when creating an Express service?

Tags: node.js, express, structure, node-modules

Hi I am structuring my Node.js project based on [this](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-project-structure-tutorial/), like so:

> - Root
>
>   - product name
>
>     - index.js: (contains requires for the product and the main export)
>     - productName.js: contains application logic
>   - test
>
>     - test1.js
>     - test2.js
>         ...

Now I have two questions

1. What should logically go in index.js? At the moment I have this (**would this be a good way to do things and what else might I include in index.js?**):

   ```
   // index.js

   var myServer = require('./myServer.js'); // "product name" = "myServer"

   module.exports = {
       run: myServer.listen
   }
   ```
2. Does it matter what I call the object key in module.exports (currently "run")? Why does the server always run when I execute index.js with `$ node index.js` how does it automatically know to run `myServer.listen`?

P.S.: I am aware of web structure auto-generation tools, I just wish to understand the logical reason for this suggested structure (the idea of not having any logic in index.js)

Comment: `index.js` is usually your *entry point* (IIRC `npm init` even uses that as the default in the `package.json`). It's where you import/require all of your modules, and that is it's only function. You may add logic if you wish, but having it only import means you don't ever have to look at it to problem-solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned this is a Express service, if it is only handling backend of some application or more specifically this is only backend application, I would suggest you change name of your index.js to server.js(Thus explicitly stating that it'll process all service requests).

But if not then even index.js is fine.

Now for

## 1

What you've put is absolutely fine, apart from this you could require all modules, routes(or controllers whatever you name them) in a way that it serves as entry point to your application. Try not to put any logic in here.

## 2

Actually the server runs because it executes the script in the file called index.js, the script says myServer.listen, now if you had written console.log("Hello World") and used $ `node index.js` it would've printed `Hello World` instead.

Node just expects and executes script that is there in index.js, in your case it is to start the server.

About the logic that why not put anything else in index.js, for me the reasoning I consider good enough is it provides abstraction as it is the entry point I don't want index.js to worry about things like what to do with this data and all. I believe it should provide a base to setup server. Thus following single responsibility to some extent. Also I won't have to touch it ever in projects lifetime unless some major change occurs e.g. I decide to shift from express to something else.

**EDIT**
Why have a key called run

You seem to have answered it yourself(in comments), you are giving or more proper description would be you're attaching an object to module.exports as it is a object similar to JSON it was supposed to have a key(which could be anything not necessarily run it could've been hii). Now if you don't want to pass a key and export only one thing that is server.listen then you could write same as `module.exports = myServer.listen;` instead of

```
module.exports = {
   hii: myServer.listen
 }
```

Note that you could export more modules using the way you did. For more details about module.exports refer [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) or better google about it as this link might expire anytime and does not seem an ideal thing to put on SO.

Comment: So if any scripts/functions in module.exports = {} are executed what is the purpose of giving that object a key (in my example "run:")?

Comment: Please refer to the edit I made based on your comment :)